# the usage of "any"

Tags: grammaticality

I was a little bored, so I just happened to read one of the information pages here on bounties, and I stumbled upon this sentence.

```
 no bounty is awarded to anyone
```

I don't study grammar academically, nor have I studied it for its own sake since leaving middle school. But this seemed a little odd to me. As far as I've learnt, "any" is often used in negative sentences; so there'd be no problem here.

However, I just feel the more appropriate sentence here would be:

```
the bounty is awarded to no one
```

But, since I can't pinpoint the grammatical error in the former, and since it was on the page of English stack exchange, learner's or not, I'm having second thoughts on my instinct.

So my question is: is the first sentence in question wrong?

Answer (score 2):

No, the first sentence is completely **correct** grammatically. It just on the author that they did not choose to use the negative pronoun (no one).
Both sentences are correct. The choice how to construct a sentence can differ with each person.